# Php PDO, class method return true while the column name in the param is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, class, methods, pdo

**I have created class having the following two methods:
Connection method is as following:**

```
private function connect(){
    try{
        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db_name};charset=utf8", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass); 
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**While here is the method for insert,update,delete and search record in table:**

```
public function dbQuery($sql,$bindVars=array()){
        try{
            $this->connect();
            $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute($bindVars);
            if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
                }
            else{
                return false;
                }
            }catch(PDOException $exc){
                return $exc->getMessage(); 
                }
            $this->con = null;
```

**Now i am using this way to (for example) insert record to my table:**

**1- fill array that could be bind to dbQuery method;**

```
$bindInputInsert = array(
                                        ':empSno'=>$empSno,
                                        ':fromCourt'=>$fromCourt,
                                        ':toCourt'=>$toCourt,
                                        ':transferDate'=>$transferDate,
                                        ':transferFromDate'=>$transferFromDate,
                                        ':causeOfTransfer'=>$causeOfTransfer,
                                        ':departmentDetails'=>$departmentDetails,
                                        ':orderNo'=>$orderNo
                                        );
```

**2-   Now prepare an insert query like this:**

```
                $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO empoffices (
                                                    empSno,
                                                    fromCourt,
                                                    toCourt,
                                                    transferDate,
                                                    transferFromDate,
                                                    causeOfTransfer,
                                                    departmentDetails,
                                                    orderNo
                                                    ) 
                              VALUES(
                                                    :empSno,
                                                    :fromCourt,
                                                    :toCourt,
                                                    :transferDate,
                                                    :transferFromDate,
                                                    :causeOfTransfer,
                                                    :departmentDetails,
                                                    :orderNo
                                                    )";
```

**3-   Send the query to dbQuery method and test record inserted or not?**

```
if($db->dbQuery($sqlInsert,$bindInputInsert)){
      echo($method->sucMsg("Info: - "," Record saved successfully")); 
      }
 else {
      echo($method->errorMsg("Error: - ","Record not saved"));
      }//end else insert()
```

**Problem i am facing with this:**
The above method is working fine for me but when if i misspelled a column name in the query it does not inserted record to table (Which is correct), but still it returns true??? while it should return false?

What i am doing wrong i am not understanding, please help me out in this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `dbQuery` only returns false if a valid query results in a `rowCount() <= 0`. When you send an invalid query, such as one with a misspelled column name, it is returning an exception, specifically `$exc->getMessage();` which is not `false`.

Try something like this instead:

```
if ($db->dbQuery($sqlInsert,$bindInputInsert) === true) {
    // success
} ...
```

This will evaluate as true if and only if `dbQuery` returns exactly `true` - not `false` *or* `$exc->getMessage();`.

Comment: yes you are right i was really ignoring the $exc->getMessage(), if i replace $exc->getMessage() with false, i think it should work for me? is it not?

Comment: @AbdulRahman Yes, replacing `$exc->getMessage()` with false should fix the problem... but then you lose your exception message, so you may want to first echo the message, then return false.

Comment: Thanks for your precious tip: i have replace the code in the catch block like this: \n   catch(.....){   $this->tempVar = $exc->getMessage(); //for debugging purpose only
     return false;} \n now if i will need to show the error message i will call for $obj->tempVar in echo function.